# Onchage ajax call using select

Tags: ajax, events, button, submit, onchange

I have this code and i have made it work with a submit button so how will I change it to a onchange and discarding the submit button? Can you guide me on how to do this?

```
echo "<form type=\"post\" action=\"\" id=\"newAjaxAudio" . $id . "\">
<select name=\"name\" id=\"aaplaylist_selection\" style=\"border: 1px solid #999999;color: #555555;font-size: 11px;height: 17px;min-width: 216px\">
    <option value='" . $thefile1 . "' >" . $thetitle1 . "</option>
    <option value='" . $thefile2 . "' >" . $thetitle2 . "</option>
</select>
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"action\" value=\"addAudioSelector1\"/>
<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Play\" style=\"font-size:11px\">
</form>
<div id=\"feedback" . $id . "\"></div>

<script type=\"text/javascript\">
jQuery('#newAjaxAudio" . $id . "').submit(ajaxSubmit);

function ajaxSubmit(){

    var newAjaxAudio" . $id . " = jQuery(this).serialize();

    jQuery.ajax({
        type:\"POST\",
        url: \"/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php\",
        data: newAjaxAudio" . $id . ",
        success:function(data){
            jQuery(\"#feedback" . $id . "\").html(data);
        }
    });

    return false;
}
</script>";
```

The Function :

```
function addAudioSelector1(){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    echo "<div id='sm2-container'></div>
    <ul class='playlist'>
        <li><a href='" . WPAUDIO_URL . "/sounds/" . $name . ".mp3'>" . $name . "</a></li>
    </ul>";
    die();
} // end Function addnewAudio
add_action('wp_ajax_addAudioSelector1', addAudioSelector1);
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_addAudioSelector1', addAudioSelector1); // not really needed
//***************************************************************************//
```

Thanks for the Help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it solved! .change() wasn't enough. Here is what I've done :

```
jQuery('#aaplaylist_selection" . $id . "').change(function() {
    jQuery(this).parents('form').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger `jQuery('#newAjaxAudio" . $id . "').submit(ajaxSubmit);` on `$("#aaplaylist_selection").change();` or directly trigger `ajaxSubmit()`

Comment: Thanks. I am fairly new to this and so not really know how to handle the submission using change(). Do I do it this way $("#aaplaylist_selection").change(jQuery('#newAjaxAudio" . $id . "').submit(ajaxSubmit)); or like this $("#aaplaylist_selection").change(ajaxSubmit());

Comment: You should wrap it in a fn: `$("#aaplaylist_selection").change(function(){ajaxSubmit()});`

Comment: ok but I have an Hidden field that needs to be passed also upon form submission, so will this be submitted too If I use change() to directly trigger ajaxSubmit only?

Comment: if it is within a form it will be passed

Comment: I did what you said but result of ajax is 0 instead of expected output of a mp3 player. This works with normal manual submission but cannot get it to work with ajax. I think the hidden field is not called since it is not activated it cannot output the html that suppose to be an mp3 link.